# Remove selected item from ListView

Tags: android, listview, select

I want to delete the selected item from the `ListView` but I can't. I've tried a lot of methods but they aren't working for me.

This is my adapter list- items are coming from the SD Card.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        FindFilesByType.this, android.R.layout.test_list_item,
                        Ringtones);
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the item from the underlying list and signal the adapter, that the dataset has changed.

Have a look at [this method](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/8fae44ccf4043d40d569c40f8b5dac23ed677e56/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/preferences/ExpandableListPreference.java#L117) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Implement the onitemclickListener and get the item(get ID) clicked in the arrayadapter and then call 
arrayList.remove([ID]);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LayoutInflater inflater=cntx.getLayoutInflater();
                View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark_row,null);

                TextView tv=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtToc);
                final TextView tv2=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtPgNo);
                mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
                System.out.println("Count Cursor"+mCursor.getCount());
                if(mCursor.getCount()<=0)
                {
                    tv.setText("No Bookmark Found");
                }
                else
                {
                tv.setText(mCursor.getString(1).toString());
                tv2.setTag(mCursor.getString(0).toString());
                tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println(position);
                        db_conn.onDelete("tab_book", mCursor.getColumnName(0),Integer.parseInt((String) tv2.getTag()));
//                      Toast.makeText(ctx,"Bookmark Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mToastTextView=new toastTextview(0, 0, ctx,listAct);
                        mToastTextView.showMessage("Bookmark Deleted");
                        refresh();
                    }
                });
                row.setTag(mCursor.getString(2).toString());
                }
                return row;
            }


        public void refresh()
        {
            mCursor=db_conn.onQueryGetCursor("tab_book",mItems,null, null, null, null, null);
            mCursor.moveToPosition(0);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            if(mCursor.getCount()<=0)
            {
//              Toast.makeText(ctx, "No Bookmark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    mFlingAct.dialogBookmark.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception3
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

       }
```