# Android - How to delete a custom listview item on button click?

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-lists

I have a custom list with two two textviews and a delete button. I want to delete the listview item when I click delete button
I have tried these answers [delete item from custom listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750007/delete-item-from-custom-listview), [Remove selected item from ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856436/remove-selected-item-from-listview), [Remove ListView items in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558591/remove-listview-items-in-android) with no luck.

This is my Adapter class

```
public class SpecialListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
Activity context;
List<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> newid = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> newname = new ArrayList<String>();

ViewHolder holder;

public SpecialListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> id, List<String> name) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return id.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtViewID;
    TextView txtViewName;
    ImageButton btnDelete;

}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.special_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtViewID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.specialId);
        holder.txtViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.specialName);

        holder.txtViewID.setText(id.get(position));
        holder.txtViewName.setText(name.get(position));

        holder.btnDelete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bDelete);
        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                id.remove(position);
                name.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }



return convertView;
}
}
```

**Edit**

Error Log:

```
12-18 17:39:46.030: D/AndroidRuntime(17893): Shutting down VM
12-18 17:39:46.030: W/dalvikvm(17893): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dc3930)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:638)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:75)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(AbstractCollection.java:229)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at .SpecialListAdapter$1.onClick(SpecialListAdapter.java:83)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-18 17:39:46.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17893):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

you are removing only from "name" `List` and you have

```
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return id.size();
}
```

so the count of list items isn't changing.

add to `onClick` line `id.remove(position);`, then `notifyDataSetChanged();`

also put this

```
holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            id.remove(position);
            name.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

outside/below `if(convertView == null){...} else {...}` and keep `ViewHolder` inside method `ViewHolder holder;` above this `if`

Comment: I've already written id.remove(). Just scroll horizontally and you'll see it. And moving setOnClickListener outside if(convertView == null){...} else {...} gives me java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at id.remove(position)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a global variable for you String Array in your Activity class...

```
List<String> globalIDArray = new List<String>();
List<String> globalNamesArray = new List<String>();
```

You set the adapter to list, like this...

```
myListView.setAdapter(new SpecialListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), globalIDArray, globalNamesArray);
```

Now on button click...

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
              globalIDArray.remove("id to remove");
              globalNamesArray.remove("name to remove");
              // now just invalidate the views and it will do remaining work automatically
              myListView.invalidateViews();
       }
}
```

Edit:

You can implement the functionality to remove item right inside the getView function of adapter. Something like this...

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.special_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtViewID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.specialId);
        holder.txtViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.specialName);

        holder.txtViewID.setText(id.get(position));
        holder.txtViewName.setText(name.get(position));

        holder.btnDelete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bDelete);

        //
        // Set tag to button so we can use ID and Name values at 'onClick'
        //
        holder.btnDelete.setTag(new ID_Name_Set(id.get(position), name.get(position)));

        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // retrieve tag object and fetch ID and Name from this object

                ID_Name_Set set = (ID_Name_Set)v.getTag();
                id.remove(set.ID);
                name.remove(set.Name);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
}

private class ID_Name_Set
{
    public String ID = "";
    public String Name = "";

    public ID_Name_Set(String id, String name)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

:)

Comment: How would I access the delete button from my Activity class!

Comment: still gives me the same error on id.remove(set.ID).

Answer (score 0):

You should add position of item into your button by following this, and then in onClick method, you should remove it from the actual list also.

```
holder.btnDelete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bDelete);
holder.btnDelete.setTag(position);
```

and in your onClick method please add those new lines :

```
int pos = (Integer)v.getTag();
//remove item from list and notifydatasetChanged
name.remove(pos);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and one more thing is, you should also add tags to your views, in the case of "convertview != null" too.

I hope this will help you, since it helps me to solve my problem.

Regards.

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work! It gives me a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException on "onClick"

Comment: can you write full error log here so i can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
```

should be

```
ArrayList<String> id;
ArrayList<String> name;
```

The `List` will be unmodified, use `ArrayList`

then use in your constructor

```
this.id = new ArrayList<String>(id);
this.name = new ArrayList<String>(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (convertView == null)
    {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.special_list_item, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();



    convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }
    holder.txtViewID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.specialId);
    holder.txtViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.specialName);

    holder.txtViewID.setText(id.get(position));
    holder.txtViewName.setText(name.get(position));

    holder.btnDelete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bDelete);
    holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            id.remove(position);
            name.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```